# Why does VLC change my video size when I convert it?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I wanted to add a logo on a video and I followed this tutorial https://www.vlchelp.com/add-logo-watermarks-over-videos-vlc/ but for some reason I don't understand, the result video lags and has ~ half the size of the original video (in Mb). Can you help me please ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't answer the question, but it solves the problem : I used Movavi to integrate my logo. It works fine.